# Images and anchor, how to apply alignment to link text?

Tags: html, css, image, anchor

I have to write HTML with Image and anchor tag. The size of images is not equal. What I need to do is align the link text 'See Projects'to right side so that they will be on the same vertical level/line. Here is my code.

```
<div>
<ul>
  <li><img src="images/layout/nokia.gif" /><a href="#">See projects</a></li>
  <li><img src="images/layout/kpn.gif" /><a href="#">See projects</a></li>
  <li><img src="images/layout/sla.gif" /><a href="#">See projects</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

All images are on the left side (length not equal). I want to show links 'See Projects' on the same vertical level. What can I do? What can be best way?

Here is code on JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chhantyal/F9TA5/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code in your CSS

```
ul li
{
    width:300px;
}
ul li a
{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/chhantyal/F9TA5/1/

```
img {
    width: 50px; */ for testing */
    height: 50px; */ for testing */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; */ for testing */
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
li {
    width: 300px;
    clear: both;
}
a {
    float: right;
    padding: 18px 0 0 0; */ Adjust this to make anchors line up vertically
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try add `"float: right;"` style to the anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Would  you use the vertical-align (bottom -> middle or top or num%)

```
li img, li a{ vertical-align:bottom }
```